# Using sed to replace text from a list of files from find

Tags: find, sed

Given the following find command:
find . | xargs grep 'userTools' -sl

How can I use sed on the results of that command?

output:

```
./file1.ext
./file2.ext
./file3.ext
```

Comment: What do you want `sed` to do?

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't clarify before. I need sed to replace the contents of each file in the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to perform some `sed` operation on the contents of each of the files rather than on the list of file names since you seem to know how to do that already. The answer depends in part on the version of `sed` you have available. If it supports the `-i` option (edit files in place), you could use `xargs` again like this:

```
find . | xargs grep 'userTools' -sl | xargs -L1 sed -i 's/this/that/g'
```

If your `sed` doesn't have the `-i` option, you could do this instead:

```
find . | xargs grep 'userTools' -sl | while read file
do
sed 's/this/that/g' "$file" > tmpfile
mv tmpfile "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find \Path_where_files_are -type f -name 'file_type' -exec  sed -e 's/"text_to_be_changed"/"text_to_be_changed_to"/' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep -slZ 'userTools' | xargs -0 sed -i 's/foo/bar/'
```

or

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/userTools/ s/foo/bar/'
```

or

```
ack -l --print0 'userTools' | xargs -0 sed -i 's/foo/bar/'
```